# How do i wait for a function (toString()) to be finish before using that variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, stream

I trying to convert a buffer to string and trying to parse it to Json. But sometimes its trying to convert to Json before string operation completes.

In the below code I was trying to convert buffer data which is in variable dat to string and parsing it to JSON. So sometimes JSON.parse throws an error (Incomplete json format to parse).

```
var apicall = {
    url: API,
    method: 'post',
    responseType: 'stream',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: body
}
axios(apicall).then((res) =>{
   var writer = new MemoryStream(null, {
       readable : true
   })
   res.data.pipe(writer)
   writer.on('data',function(dat){  
       console.log(dat);
       var e = dat.toString();
       var jsondata = JSON.parse(e);
       console.log(jsondata);
   });
}).catch((e)=>{
    console.log(e);
})
```

Request someone to help me how to wait for toString function to complete its process

Comment: is this not an issue with accessing the `writer` stream before it is told what to do with the stream? Wold moving the `pipe` to after the `writer.on` declaration change anything? Never used axios, am curious.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is that you will receive the response in chunks the default value is 16KB so if you have a json bigger than that it will come in multiple chunks.

> One way to fix your algorithm is to store all those chunks into a separate array and once the stream is completed *end* event, to parse it:

```
let body = [];
writer.on('data', (chunk) => {
  body.push(chunk);
}).on('end', () => {
  body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
  // at this point, `body` has all the chunks stored in as a string
  // here you will be able to JSON.parse the body
  const json = JSON.parse(body);
});
```

The downside of the approach is that it will not work for very big files that exceed 1.7GB because they will not fit into memory.